# how to remove spring aop proxy dynamically?

Tags: spring-aop

Given the following Aspect defination,

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class DefAspect {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("DefAspect");
    
    @Around("execution(* com.jd.brick.service.OrderService.saveOrder(..))")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object value;
    
        try {
            value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw throwable;
        } finally {
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            String msg = String.format("%s.%s took %s ms",
                    proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getSimpleName(),
                    proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                    duration);
            log.info(msg);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Spring will automatically make a proxy object, which will log the duration of method invocation.

But in some situation, the generated proxy object need to be removed.

In general, spring bean can be removed from BeanDefinitionRegistry.

```java
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class, args);

    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

    for(String beanName : ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
        System.out.println(beanName);
        registry.removeBeanDefinition(beanName);
    }
```

As for AOP situation, the bean name seems not easy determined.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a wonderful example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898): You are describing **how** you want to solve your problem instead of explaining **what** you are trying to achieve and what the actual problem is. Even though it is in theory possible to dynamically remove a Spring AOP advice from a proxy, it smells like bad design. Probably there are better solutions to your problem, but first I need a chance to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Please next time notify me with a comment, because I do not get notifications for edits, only for new questions, answers or comments. Anyway, your update does not answer my question, it is still the XY problem. "In some situations, the generated proxy object needs to be removed" does not qualify as an explanation **why** you think you need to unregister a bean. Besides, before you said you want to unregister the AOP advice, now suddenly it is the whole bean? I am more confused than before. If you cannot explain your problem, nobody can help you.